# My Ender 3 malfunctions with touchscreen

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, firmware

Yesterday, I upgraded my Ender 3 with a Creality touchscreen that is compatible with it. However, since the installation, it gets stuck on the loading screen once the bar fills up. I tried different versions and even built my own, but they all gave me one of three responses:

- Stuck on loading screen
- `Firmware unexpected. TF may be corrupted. Try renaming or using different TF.`
- Take me to the interface with half the buttons/widgets responding and no functionality.

And I can't reinstall the old LCD because I had to cut its cable to disconnect it.

I also asked the Bing AI, which gave me tips that didn't work.
Any tips from **this** community?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the screen itself needs a firmware update?

Comment: yes. i tried installing my crtouch since the half functional interface had an auto-leveling option but it still dont work. However, it eliminated it to only giving the error and freezing after the bar fills up.

Comment: Thank you. I realized the screen is different from the printer itself. However, still haven't tried it yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Agarza was right](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/22889/my-ender-3-malfunctions-with-touchscreen/22957#comment41201_22889).

> Have you checked to see if the screen itself needs a firmware update?

I inserted the SD card into the wrong place. I finally got it to work by inserting the SD card with the DWIN folder into the touchscreen itself (after unscrewing the housing) and successfully flashed the working version of the firmware.